# How to input data into a single cell using a for loop in R

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, cell

I am currently trying to assign groups in my data based on a previously collected variable. I want to automatically loop through my previously collected variable and assign groups via a new variable. If the measure is above a 38, I want to assign that person to group 1. All others will be group 0. I tried to execute this with the below code, but it does not seem to work.

```
for(i in 345) {                                                                                                           
 if (df_37wks$qchat_total[[i]] > 38) {                                                                                             
    df_37wks$qchat_group[[i]] <- 1
 } else {
     df_37wks$qchat_group[[i]] <- 0
 }
}
```

Where `df_37wks` is the DataFrame, `qchat_total` is the previously collected measure, and `qchat_group` is the variable where I want to store my factor variable (either 0 or 1).

The `qchat_group` variable has already been created and filled with NAs. Any advice on why this is going wrong would be greatly appreciated!

I expected this to iterate through all of the rows in `qchat_total`, evaluate whether the the value is greater than 38, and enter either a 1 or a 0 in `qchat_group` based on this information. Nothing happens when I run this code block, the `qchat_group` remains empty with NAs.

Executing `df_37wks$qchat_total[1]` prints out the appropriate cell, and

```
 if (df_37wks$qchat_total[[1]] > 38) {
   print("Hello")
}
```

Prints as expected, so I believe it has something to do with the for loop itself and not the if statement.

Comment: `df_37wks$chat_group = ifelse(df_37wks$qchat_total > 38, 1, 0)`

Comment: `i in 345` is not really a loop, it's just setting `i = 345` once. You probably meant `i in 1:345`.

Comment: @JonSpring thank you! That is a really elegant solution, and it worked perfectly for me!

Comment: Another alternative, a smidge shorter: `df_37wks$chat_group = as.numeric(df_37wks$qchat_total > 38)`